# How to calculate cash flow using calc fields?

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, firebird, firebird2.5, cumulative-sum

I'm programming a simple cash flow app, using Delphi 7, firebird 2.5 with InterBase components. The table in question was created like this:

```sql
create table movimentos
(
id  d_inteiro not null,
date_start d_data not null,
date_end    d_data,
value   d_valor,
user    d_inteiro,
tipo_movimento d_inteiro not null, -- Indicates if it is Debit or Credit
primary key(id),
foreign key(user) references usuarios(id),
foreign key(tipo_movimento) references tipoMovimento(id)
)
```

I added a calculated field in the query inside my DM and connected a DBGrid to it. What it basically has to do is to show my balance, using sum when the entry is credit( especified in the db) and sub when debit( duh).

For this, I have to get the value of the LAST balance row, sum(or sub) the value of the new entry and put this new ammount in the new insertion.

Well, I know how to calculate values in the same row and put it in another column, but cannot find anything about getting previous row value and using it in the next.

What would be the simpler way to accomplish that?

Edited: 
Complementing my question. What I would like to do is somehting like this(simplifying the table a little bit):

```
Id   date_start   value   balance  
1    03/05/15     +200     200  
2    03/08/15     +1000   1200  
3    03/09/15     -300     900
```

Now, if I added a new entry for date `03/06/15` all the rows would have to be recalculated, like this:

```
Id   date_start   value   balance  
1    03/05/15     +200     200
4    03/06/15     +500     700
2    03/08/15     +1000   1700  
3    03/09/15     -300    1400
```

How to create, calculate and show this `BALANCE` column is basically what i'm looking for.
Thanks Again.

Comment: Have you considered using SQL and RUNSUM?  Instead of a flag for debit and credit, use + or - amounts on your Value field, then it's a simple RUNSUM(Value) as Balance...

Comment: You can't do this with calculated fields. Calculated fields only have access to the current row of the data, unless you want to use a separate query in your `OnCalcFields` event that runs a separate SQL statement for every single row of your table. You need to do it in your SQL statement; you're looking to calculate a *running total*, and there are lots of questions here related to doing so in SQL.

Comment: With  some DB servers it is possible using 'window functions' [Look at `lag` function in the PostgreSQL for example.](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-window.html)

Comment: @Abelisto, PostgreSQL is a great DBMS that I think it's worth to migrate to, but this is about dying Firebird (sorry for saying this so).

Comment: @TLama Window functions have been added in Firebird 3 (currently in beta).

Comment: I'm going to presume that you did a search here for `http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[sql]+calculate+running+total` after I provided the term. None of those results were of any use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

InterBase components do not support `InternalCalc` fields, which are suitable for such client-side calculations. Although it is better to do that server-side.

In Firebird you can use context variables to calculate running totals:

```
SELECT m.*,
  CAST(rdb$get_context('USER_TRANSACTION', 'BALANCE') AS d_valor) AS BALANCE,
  rdb$set_context('USER_TRANSACTION', 'BALANCE', COALESCE(CAST(rdb$get_context('USER_TRANSACTION', 'BALANCE') AS d_valor), 0) + m.value) AS DUMMY
FROM movimentos m
ORDER BY date_start
```

Another solutions would be doing your desired calculations inside a stored procedure using a `FOR SELECT` and iterating over data.

```
BALANCE = 0;

FOR SELECT id, data_start, value
FROM movimentos
ORDER BY date_start
INTO :ID, :DATA_START, :VALUE
DO
BEGIN
  BALANCE = BALANCE + VALUE;
  SUSPEND;
END
```

To apply Debit/Credit use `IIF` to convert `tipo_movimento` to +1/-1, if it is not:

```
value * IIF(tipo_movimento = ?, +1, -1)
```

Comment: As I never used context variables before I would prefer to do it with procedures if possible. But in your example posted above I would only get the final total as far as I understand, and that's not what I'm looking for. Gonna edit my question to see if I make myself clearer, thanks for helping though.

Comment: It does exactly what you are looking for. Assuming your stored procedure has `ID, DATA_START, VALUE, BALANCE` as its output parameters, the  `SUSPEND` command every time outputs a record containing the calculated balance.

Comment: Finally got it, Thanks for the support. One final question, as I'm "creating" this balance column at runtime, how do I link it to my dbgrid in my application? Thanks again